# Giving injective formulas for a function f: $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow L$ given a set $L = \{(a,b)\mid a,b ∈ \mathbb N\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Let $L = \{(a,b)\mid a,b ∈ \mathbb N\}$

$L$ is the set of all lattice points in the first quadrant (all points in first quadrant whose coordinates are natural numbers make $L$)

a. Give a formula that makes the function  f: $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow L$ injective. (Where Natural numbers is the domain and $L$ is the codomain)

Just confused as to how there could be a binary operation or formula that leads from and element from the domain of $\mathbb{N}$ to form two elements in the codomain of L, since L is the set of lattice points $(a,b)$ containing two elements.
For example, if I tried to do $f(x) = 2x$, it would be 2 times any element from the domain $\mathbb{N}$, but that would create another element in the domain of $\mathbb{N}$. **I need a formula that uses elements in $\mathbb{N}$ to create elements in the domain of $L$, while also having that formula be injective**

Comment: Yes, you somehow need to extract two natural numbers out of each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. One way to do this is to write $n = 2^{a-1} m$ where $m$ is odd. Then use $a$ as the first natural number associated to $n$, and $m$ as the second.

Comment: @MarkWildon That's overkill, since you just want injective. You are giving an injective and surjective function. There are *much* simpler functions which are injective...

Comment: is it possible to do something like 2(a,b)? could you apply binary operation to coordinates, or is that invalid?

Comment: I could swear that this question was posted last night.

Comment: @AsafKaragila yea, they removed it... so I shortened the problem and tried to clarify and add more context and posted

Comment: Ah, very well then. That explains why I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Isn't  $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N^2$, $f=\{(n,(a,m))\mid n=2^{a-1}m, \textrm{ with } m \textrm{ odd}\}$ only injective?

Comment: @MarkWildon is there a simpler injective formula between L and $\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: Ah, yes, @Fred, but it is a short step from being onto. And there are *much* *much* easier functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clear up my earlier comment: as Thomas Andrews points out, there are many, much simpler, injections from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^2$. For example, $n \mapsto (n,1)$ is fine. In words: use $n$ as the first coordinate and fix the second coordinate at $1$.

I somehow misread the question as asking for a bijection $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^2$, but my comment doesn't work for this because $m$ is always odd. This could be fixed by defining

$$ n \mapsto (a,\frac{m+1}{2}) $$

where $n = 2^{a-1} m$ and $m$ is odd. There are many other, probably simpler, ways to do this.

Comment: Thank you! But is that a formula or just a mapping? so for example, f(x)↦ (n,1) or f(x)↦ (1,n) are both **formulas** that are injective, correct? I sort of understand it but could you explain the injective part a little? Such as just slightly explain why it is injective/how you know it is injective.

Comment: What do you think a function is, @gticecream8? Why is $f(n)=2n$ a function, but $f(n)=(n,1)$ is not a function?

Comment: It is a function but it's not a formula, since you can't solve for (n,1) but you can solve for 2n. you can only plug numbers into (n,1). For 2n, you can plug in a number for n then solve. I need a **formula** for the injective function (n,1)

Comment: Dear gticecream8: let $g(n) = (n,1)$. I claim that this is both a formula for $g(n)$, and a specification of a function $g : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^2$. To solve for $(n,1)$ just note that the unique element of $\mathbb{N}$ that maps to $(n,1)$ is $n$ itself.

Comment: Ah I see, yes that's fine sorry about my confusion. What of a surjective function then? I'm unable to find a surjective function with a formula. In other words, what about a function that can map $\mathbb{N}$ to all elements in my set L

Comment: I just realized, if you graphed (n,1) it wouldn't be one-to-one, so it wouldn't be injective... would (n,$n^2$) be injective?

Comment: Note that $n \mapsto (n,1)$ does not associate natural numbers with natural numbers, but associates natural numbers with ordered pairs. You might want to graph it in the three-dimensional space, assigning some $(y,z)$ for each $x$. This function is as one-to-one as $n \mapsto n$ is. The function $n \mapsto(n,n^2)$ is likewise injective.

Comment: The case for a surjective function maybe calls for a more elaborate definition, as the one Mark suggested. You should have **every** $y$ and $z$ **uniquely** related to every $x$ from the domain. Every $a$ and $m$ will define a unique $n$ (and every $n$ can be defined in such terms).